# Regexp match when only one occurence found

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I want to check if a file has only one extension. I tried to use the groups, but they don't allow me to verify that they appear only once (I didn't find out how to do it)

[Here is an example used](https://regex101.com/r/86mv3J/1):

```
\.(js|jsx)$
```

For example, if *js* and *jsx* are allowed:

```
test.js -> should match
test.jsx -> should match
test.ts -> should not match
test.js.jsx -> should not match
```

Any string with `.js.jsx`, `.jsx.jsx`, `.jsx.js` or `.js.js` at the end are not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean to say there can only be one single dot? `^[^.]*\.jsx?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/86mv3J/3

Comment: Or do you mean you just missed to enable the `m` and `g` flags at regex101? See https://regex101.com/r/86mv3J/4

Comment: No, the problem with a single dot verification is a path can contain multiple dots, but not the extension.

Comment: Then how do you tell an extension from a non-extension? Do you only call `js` and `jsx` an extension?

Comment: Yes in this example, but not both at same time.

Comment: Then `(?<!\.jsx?)\.jsx?$` will work. For non-ES2018, `^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?){2}$).*\.jsx?$`.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only target modern browsers that are ECMAScript 2018+ compliant, you can use

```js
/(?<!\.jsx?)\.jsx?$/
```

For other environments that are not ES2018+ compliant, you cna use

```js
/^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?){2}$).*\.jsx?$/
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/LmZU9c/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/LmZU9c/2).

If you need it case insensitive, add the `i` flag:

```js
/(?<!\.jsx?)\.jsx?$/i
/^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?){2}$).*\.jsx?$/i
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\.jsx?)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if - immediately to the left of the current location - there is a `.js` or `.jsx` substring
- `\.jsx?` - a `.js` or `.jsx` string
- `$` - end of string.

The `^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?){2}$).*\.jsx?$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:\.jsx?){2}$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and two occurrences of `.js` or `.jsx` at the end of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than any line break chars as many as possible
- `\.jsx?` - `.js` or `.jsx`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`\.\w+\.\w+` this regex expression matches files with more than one extension. However, it may be necessary to do some string operations first.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a global match to get all extensions and then compare the last two extensions:

Match all extensions:

```
/\..+?\b/g
```

Test valid extensions:

```
/\.jsx?/
```

Here is a example:

```js
const ALL_EXTENSION = /\..+?\b/g;
const ALLOW_EXTENSION = /\.jsx?/;

const files = [
  'test.js',
  'test.jsx',
  'test.ts',
  'test.js.js',
  'test.js.jsx',
  'test.jsx.js',
  'test.jsx.jsx',
  'test.js.ok.js',
  'test.jsx.ok.jsx',
];

files.forEach((file) => {
  const match = file.match(ALL_EXTENSION);
  const allow =
    (match &&
      ALLOW_EXTENSION.test(match[match.length - 1]) &&
      !ALLOW_EXTENSION.test(match[match.length - 2])) ||
    false;
  console.log(file, allow);
});
```

Comment: The idea of counting `\.jsx?` is good, but then, is `blah.js.test.js` considered valid? It is, from what I understand from the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated my answer according to the new description of the question. Anyway, your's is the best one.